# way to run android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android and I try to create my first new project but I failed and show much error I solved except the last one

I already download (android Studio, JDK, SDK, Gradle)

**the error:**

> Could not GET
> 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'.
> Received status code 403 from server: 
> Forbidden  Disable Gradle
> 'offline mode' and sync project

**note:I need to run java without kotlin**

more information:
Android Studio 4.1.3 
java version 1.8.0_91
gradle version 7.0
kotlin version 1.4.31

Comment: In the file `build.gradle` in your project, replace the part that says `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: Doesn't still work after have applied @Tenfour04's options, try disabling offline mod.

View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar.

Comment: i try it and it show error "SSL peer shut down incorrectly", 
i press File>invalidet caches but sill the error

Answer (score 0):

In the file build.gradle in your project, replace the part that says jcenter() with mavenCentral()

and to solve the SSL ERROR
in file gradle-wrapper.properties
replace this line

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

with

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

thanks, guys

Comment: Nothing is working. Still Forbidden 403. 
Bintray.com is not able access. Same problem here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks